# Procfile in Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

Can somebody help me regarding on how can i solve my problem on Heroku. Im new to Heroku.
This warning always appear.  WARNING:No Procfile detected, using the default web server (webrick). Im using Rails 4. Thank in advance

Comment: What server are you trying to use?  Unicorn or something?Have you read through this yet? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

Comment: Im using unicorn server

Comment: i restart the heroku. and its ok now. I just having a  at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed". Right now

Comment: ok so I will need to see the full log in order to help, that is probably a different question as well.  I guess you can click this as answered or not depending if you feel my answer solved the issue you posted about.

Comment: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=XXXXXX request_id=89f5bea5-e3c3-4d06-af05-0aef758216fa fwd="49.147.56.19" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error itself is pretty self-explanatory. No `Procfile` is detected, so in your root directory create a file called `Procfile`.

As you stated in your comment you are using the `Unicorn` server so inside the `Procfile` put this code.

```
 web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
```

*I am assuming you created a unicorn.rb file*

push to github, push to heroku and see if that works.

The `Procfile` holds the command for starting the server, and any options you need to pass to that. Your app was crashing because the command to start the server was not there at all.